# Error converting .py file to .exe file using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a .py file that i want to convert in .exe file. I used cx_Freeze for converting that. But after converting when i'm trying to run the .exe file it shows following error-

```
H:\Python\Practice\Download Bollywood Song\build\exe.win32-3.5>cmd /K "download_bollywood_song.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
from .packages.six.moves.queue import LifoQueue, Empty, Full
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named 'queue'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 12, in <module>
__import__(name + "__init__")
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 24, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "download_bollywood_song.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 24, in <module>
from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 11, in <module>
from .packages import chardet
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
import urllib3
ImportError: No module named 'urllib3'

H:\Python\Practice\Download Bollywood Song\build\exe.win32-3.5>
```

I tried to install "queue" module using `pip install queue` command.
But it shows following error-

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\USER PC>pip install queue
Collecting queue
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement queue (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for queue

C:\Users\USER PC>
```

How to solve this issue ??
I'm using python 3.5 on windows 7 32 bit.

**EDIT**
Here is my code that i want to convert to .exe file.

```
import time;
import requests;
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup;

def get_page(url):

    response = requests.get(url);
    html = response.text;
    return html;

def make_soup(html):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser");
    return soup;

def get_movie_link(words):

    movie_name = "";
    first = True;

    for word in words:
        if(not first):
            movie_name+=" ";
        first = False;
        movie_name+=word;

    movie_link = "";
    movie_name = movie_name.title();
    first_character = movie_name[0];

    url = "http://songsmp3.co/1/bollywood-music/list-" + first_character + ".html";
    html = get_page(url);
    soup = make_soup(html);
    movie_list = soup.find_all("div",class_="list_inside_box");
    movies = [];

    for movie in movie_list:
        movies = movie.find_all("a");
    for movie in movies:
        name = movie.get_text();
        link = movie.get("href");
        if(name.find(movie_name) > -1):
            movie_link = link;
            break;
    return movie_name,movie_link;

def get_download_link(movie_name,movie_link):

    if(movie_link == ""):
        return movie_link;
    if(movie_link.find("http://songsmp3.co") == -1):
        movie_link = "http://songsmp3.co" + movie_link;

    html = get_page(movie_link);
    soup = make_soup(html);
    links = soup.find_all("div",class_="link-item-zip");

    download_link = "";
    for link in links:
        data = link.find("a");
        song_link = data.get("href");
        if(download_link == ""):
            download_link = song_link;

    return download_link;

def download_songs(movie_name,download_link):

    if(download_link == ""):
        return;

    file_name = movie_name + ".zip";
    response = requests.get(download_link, stream=True);
    file = open(file_name, "wb");
    file.write(response.content);
    file.close();
    return;

start_time = time.clock();
#print("N.B: Becareful about spelling.");
words = input().split();

movie_name,movie_link = get_movie_link(words);
download_link = get_download_link(movie_name,movie_link);
download_songs(movie_name,download_link);

end_time = time.clock();
print("Execution Time: %.2f"%(end_time-start_time));
```

And here is my setup.py file code-

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable;

setup(name="Download Bollywood Song",version="1.0.1",description="Download specified movie songs",
      executables=[Executable("download_bollywood_song.py")]);
```

Comment: Any solution??  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the real problem is without pasting your actual code here.

Bear with the fact that in Python 3.x, you have `Queue` instead of `queue`.(try `from multiprocessing import Queue`). As specified in other simillar threads, try doing:

```
import requests
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

And get rid of the `urllib3` module. `requests` may do whatever you're trying to achieve as well.

More, make sure you don't have any `queue.py` in your working directory.

As a last resort, I've always found it easier to work with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: I have added my code. and i don't have any queue.py file in my working directory. i'm using requests already, no urllib3 @Dex-ter

Comment: @Dex-ter Thanks for suggesting pyinstaller. It's really cool and easy to use. :D